# Matlab to R code "~exist" code conversion

Tags: r, matlab

I'm trying to convert *MATLAB* code to *R* code. In *MATLAB* I have the following

```
if (~exist('Arch', 'var')), Arch = 5; end
if ~isfield(opt,'HIS'), opt.HIS = 1; end
if ~isfield(opt,'HERS'), opt.HERS = inf; end
if ~isfield(opt,'MINE'), opt.MINE = 0; end
```

~ symbol in *MATLAB* is interpreted as [Find logical NOT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html)

thanks to the replies below the first line of the code becomes

```
 if (!all(sapply(c("A","B"), exists))){A = 5}
```

while for the second part the following code do not seems to work. *isfield(S,field)* in *MATLAB* returns 1 if field is the name of a field of the structure array S. Otherwise, it returns 0. In my case S=opt is a *struct* R function.
How to properly translate the ~ in this part?

```
if (!isfield(opt,'HIS') {opt.HIS <- 1}                                   
if (!isfield(opt,'HERS') {opt.HERS <- inf}                                   
if (!isfield(opt,'MINE') {opt.MINE <- 0}
```

Comment: `exist('A', 'B')` is not valid MATLAB. It should be `exist('A', 'variable')`, or just `exist('A')`. You cannot test for existence of multiple variables in MALTAB. The code around it seems to indicate `B` is not even a variable and not relevant. Are you copy-pasting the actual code, or did you change things when asking the question here?

Comment: i did edit it, very valid observation.

Comment: A few comments: (1) please don't edit your question to include answers (that's what the answers are for ...) (2) is @NickRaven correct that `exist('Arch', 'var')` isn't valid MATLAB code? if so, can you please edit your question to specify what you're actually doing in MATLAB? (3) I don't know what `isfield()` does in MATLAB, so I can't help you translate to R unless your question explains it ... (4) "do not work" is too vague - do you get an error? the wrong answer? if it's the wrong answer, what was the expected correct answer?

Comment: @Ben: `exist('Arch', 'var')` is valid MATLAB code, `exist('Arch', 'B')` is not. The 2nd argument is a parameter, it tells MATLAB what type of thing to look for (variable, file, function, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo.  (to the OP: best not to assume everyone knows MATLAB ...)

Comment: `if (~exist('Arch', 'var')), Arch = 5; end` is one way in MATLAB to see if an input variable `Arch` is given (all input variables are optional), and assign a default value if it's not. I'm sure R has some different mechanism for this that would be more suitable. I don't know R though.

Comment: The other lines check to see if the struct `opt` has some fields, and adds those fields with default values if they don't exist. Again, I'm sure R has some typical way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In R, `exists()` only applies to a single symbol.  Maybe `!all(sapply(c("A","B"), exists))` ?  (This assumes that `exist` in MATLAB is true only if all of the symbols specified are defined.)

From what I can tell from the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html), it seems that the analogue of `!isfield(opt,'MINE')` would be `!('MINE' %in% names(opt))`, but it might depend on the class of `opt` (e.g. if it's an S4 object that won't work).

Comment: thanks, that seems to work perfectly. I edited my question because the use of the same symbol  "~"  appears again. I would appreciate it if you had the time to see it and comment about it.