# Determine if input is structure array field in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert some code from *MATLAB* to *R*. In *MATLAB* [`isfield(S,field)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html) is the way to determine if input is structure array field. e.g. in *MATLAB* the following statement returns 0.1 when the if statement is TRUE.

```
if isfield(opt,'Nick'), opt.Nick = 0.1 end
```

Is there a corresponding command in R that would perform the same procedure?

Comment: do you have two StackOverflow accounts ... ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269208/matlab-to-r-code-exist-code-conversion/63269272#63269272 It's allowed (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388984/what-are-the-rules-governing-multiple-accounts-i-e-sockpuppets), but it's confusing.  You can [merge them if you like](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible alternative in R (using `List` to represent structure in MATLAB):

```
if ("Nick" %in% names(opt)) {
  opt$Nick <- 0.1
}
```

such that

```
> str(opt)
List of 2
 $ Ida : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Nick: num 0.1
```

**Dummy Data**

```
> str(opt)
List of 2
 $ Ida : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ Nick: logi NA
```